# How to transform a dataset's mean and standard deviation with different values per column in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, calculated-columns

Recently I have been looking into statistical simulation, and after generating random data to match the specifications of a correlation matrix, I want to transform each column to have a specific mean and standard deviation. I was successfully able to do that in the following code, but it is very messy and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

```
    #Input Correlation Matrix
    sigma <- matrix(c(1.00, -0.03, 0.39, -0.05, -0.08,
                      -0.03, 1.00, 0.07, -0.23, -0.16,
                       0.39, 0.07, 1.00, -0.13, -0.29,
                      -0.05, -0.23, -0.13, 1.00, 0.34,
                      -0.08, -0.16 ,-0.29, 0.34, 1.00), nr=5, byrow=TRUE)
    rownames(sigma) <-c("Exercise", "Hardiness", "Fitness", "Stress", "Illness")
    colnames(sigma) <-c("Exercise", "Hardiness", "Fitness", "Stress", "Illness")

    #The Choleski Decomposition Random Data Generator
    N <- 373
    L = chol(sigma)
    nvars = dim(L)[1]

    # Random variables that follow the sigma correlation matrix
    r = t(L) %*% matrix(rnorm(nvars*N), nrow=nvars, ncol=N)
    r = t(r)

    sample = as.data.frame(r)

    #Transform to appropriate means and standard deviations
    sample$Exercise <- c(((sample$Exercise - mean(sample$Exercise))/sd(sample$Exercise))*66.5+40.9)
    sample$Hardiness <- c(((sample$Hardiness - mean(sample$Hardiness))/sd(sample$Hardiness))*3.8+0)
    sample$Fitness <- c(((sample$Fitness - mean(sample$Fitness))/sd(sample$Fitness))*18.4+67.1)
    sample$Stress <- c(((sample$Stress - mean(sample$Stress))/sd(sample$Stress))*6.7+4.8)
    sample$Illness <- c(((sample$Illness - mean(sample$Illness))/sd(sample$Illness))*624.8+716.7)
    sample <- as.data.frame(sample)
```

It is the last bit of code labeled "Transform to appropriate means and standard deviations" that I was hoping to simplify. The following are the means and standard deviations for each of the column variables (in order):

```
    means <-c(40.9, 0, 67.1, 4.8, 716.7)
    sdevs <-c(66.5, 3.8, 18.4, 6.7, 624.8)
```

Thank you for your help and the willingness to share your knowledge! I am looking forward to hearing your input!

Comment: BTW, you should have a look in here too, especially when it comes to some caveats concerning such methods: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-simulate-data-that-satisfy-specific-constraints-such-as-having-specific-m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scale` and `sweep`:

```
sample <- scale(as.matrix(sample),TRUE,TRUE)
sample <- sweep(sample,2,sdevs,"*")
sample <- sweep(sample,2,means,"+")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler and very easy to follow!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` you can loop over your columns  like this :

```
means <-c(40.9, 0, 67.1, 4.8, 716.7)
sdevs <-c(66.5, 3.8, 18.4, 6.7, 624.8)
mm <- colMeans(sample)
sapply(seq_along(mm),function(i){
   c(sample[,i] -mm[i]/sd((sample[,i])))*sdevs[i]+means[i]
})
```

Comment: This is a very good solution! I like how it follows the original z-transformation formula. Thank you so much!